# Application permanently launches with transparency applied. Where can I find the configuration causing this behavior?

Tags: configuration, display, debugging

Generally, where do I find configurations that might be causing this & how do I debug such an issue?

In this specific case, the main thing I did that could have caused this is using `transset-df opacity`. However, an odd behaviour is when I use `transset-df 1` and click Emacs. It becomes opaque again - only to be instantly reset when I click on the Emacs window next time.

I've tried uninstalling Emacs (just to check) to no avail. This is not as a result of my emacs config having similar problems with `emacs -q`

Based on this, I figured it has to be a configuration that is being applied only for my application of Emacs. But I can't seem to find anything in my normal `~/.` files that might be causing this.

[image: Emacs permanently starts with transparency]

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to have indeed been affected by my `.Xresources` file (`.Xdefaults` can be a culprit too).

For Emacs specifically should use `emacs -Q` to not use Xresources as well when checking.